# Java FX Layouts problem

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Таблица которая несмотря на **AnchorPane** не разворачивается на всю область, а зависит только от **prefHeight** и **prefWidth**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" type="BorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <HBox prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <JFXComboBox fx:id="searchFilter" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="211.0">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXComboBox>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="searchTextField" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="286.0" promptText="Введіть комбінацію">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXTextField>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnSearch" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="152.0" text="ПОШУК">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="15.0" left="20.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnOK" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="ОК">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnCancel" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Відміна">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <center>
            <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="370.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <columnResizePolicy>
                  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
               </columnResizePolicy>
            </TableView>
         </center>
         <bottom>
            <Pagination fx:id="pagination" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </bottom>
      </BorderPane>
   </center>
</fx:root>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот fxml файл как абстрактный класс может иметь несколько контроллеров

UPD:
Нашел очаг проблем. Дело в **setPageFactory** от **pagination**. В моей ситуации он возвращал **AnchorPane**(неудачный копипаст из другого класса), теперь возвращает **BorderPane** но вызывает **Exception**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: cycle detected: parent = StackPane@7d2c0b5d[styleClass=page], node = BorderPane[id=borderPane]
```

Что он должен возвращать? FXML файл обновлен

```
pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage); // вызов в initialize

public BorderPane createPage(int pageIndex) {
    try {


        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        fromIndex = pageIndex * 40;

        toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + 40, owner.getContactCount());

        loadDataFromDatabase();


        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList((int)fromIndex, (int)toIndex)));

        borderPane.setCenter(tableView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Switch page exception: " + e);
    }



    return borderPane;
}
```

Comment: Привидите пример, как вы создаете колонки и сетити их в таблицу

Comment: @AndrewBystrov добавил к посту

Comment: А если удалить VBox и AnchorPane, а таблицу сетить в центр borderPane, проблема остается?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov без них все ок, но у меня pagination, а в центр можно поставить только один элемент, тоесть в боттоме кнопки, в центре таблица, сверху фильтры, распределение на страницы(pagination) без этого VBox негде поставить, разве что они как-то по-другому взаимодействую(я поверх pagination ставлю tableview)

Comment: Вставил ваш `fxml` в `SceneBuilder` один в один, проблема не воспроизвелась и всё гуд. Может ( хотя вряд ли ) прикреплённый `css` что-то ломает?

Comment: @ЛеонардоДикаприо вы можете вставить в центр еще один бордер пейн, в его центр воткнуть тайбл вью а в боттом уже ваш пагинатор

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: @AndrewBystrov отличная идея, и в превью scene builder'a просто идеально отображает. а по делу таблица превращается в квадратик 100 на 100 пикселей и упирается в левый нижний угол. наверное дело не в fxml.

Comment: @AndreyM дело в том что оно на правду в preview все отлично отображает, а когда вызываешь окно из самой программы то нет

Comment: @AndreyM очистил css, ситуация не изменилась

Comment: Если убрать pagination тогда все отлично отображает. но у меня большие запросы, без пагинатора долго окно открываться будет

Comment: @AndrewBystrov обновил вопрос.нашел проблему. что можешь сказать по этому поводу?

Comment: `borderPane.setCenter(tableView);` зачем это? Он и так там находится. Имхо пора перебираться из комментариев в чат.

Comment: @AndreyM из комментариев в чат это в ответы? никогда не задавал вопросы на stackoverflow раньше, не знаю что тут и как. я кинул exception в ответы